# Finding the root cause of IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: windows-10, bsod

We've got a box that randomly stops with a `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`. We've got a full memory dump.

It certainly looks network related. How would I go about diving deeper into this to figure out the exact culprit (if possible)?

The system was upgraded from Windows Embedded Standard 7 to Windows 10 IoT LTSC 2019 a few months ago. Prior to the upgrade it was working fine.

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000020, memory referenced
Arg2: 00000002, IRQL
Arg3: 00000002, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: e1ab478f, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

VirtualToOffset: dab02a04 not properly sign extended
VirtualToOffset: dab0274c not properly sign extended

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2124

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 10624

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2546

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 29492

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 86

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: rs5_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2018-09-14T14:34:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.17763.1


BUGCHECK_CODE:  a

BUGCHECK_P1: 20

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 2

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffffffe1ab478f

READ_ADDRESS:  00000020 

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFFFFFE363A000

TRAP_FRAME:  e3639d7c -- (.trap 0xffffffffe3639d7c)
ErrCode = 00000002
eax=40c6fc26 ebx=f6996710 ecx=00000000 edx=0001e553 esi=e3639f30 edi=e0ec4300
eip=e1ab478f esp=e3639df0 ebp=e3639eb0 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010297
nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0x24f:
e1ab478f 894120          mov     dword ptr [ecx+20h],eax ds:0023:00000020=????????
Resetting default scope

STACK_TEXT:  
e3639cd0 e1b8d4d5     0000000a 00000020 00000002 nt!KiBugCheck2
    <Intermediate frames may have been skipped due to lack of complete unwind>
e3639cd0 e1ab478f (T) 0000000a 00000020 00000002 nt!KiTrap0E+0x3a5
    <Intermediate frames may have been skipped due to lack of complete unwind>
e3639eb0 e1ab3fef (T) e3639f18 00000000 00000001 nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs+0x24f
e3639ff4 e1b8e97e     ed2f38cc 00000000 00000000 nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x10f
ed2f38f0 d03a0baa     b56344b2 cbfe93d0 ed2f3b70 nt!KiDispatchInterrupt+0x2e
ed2f3940 d038b222     cbfe93d0 00012087 cbfe9301 afd!AfdEventSelect+0x13a
ed2f3ae8 e1dd9b69     cbfe9301 00000001 035fec54 afd!AfdFastIoDeviceControl+0x2e2
ed2f3bb8 e1dd993a     00000000 00000000 035fec68 nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x229
ed2f3be4 e1b873ab     00000f58 00000c58 00000000 nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x2a
    <Intermediate frames may have been skipped due to lack of complete unwind>
ed2f3be4 77ed0c80 (T) 00000f58 00000c58 00000000 nt!KiSystemServicePostCall
    <Intermediate frames may have been skipped due to lack of complete unwind>
035fec14 77ecf47a (T) 740e2362 00000f58 00000c58 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
035fec18 740e2362     00000f58 00000c58 00000000 ntdll!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0xa
035fec84 75cc008d     00000f58 00000f08 00000001 mswsock!WSPEventSelect+0x1d2
035fecb8 706cd103     00000f58 00000f08 00000001 WS2_32!WSAEventSelect+0xdd
035fee20 706ccf43     00003e68 00000000 0000000d dhcpcore!AsyncSelect+0x71
035fee64 706ccdbb     026b8370 035ff2d4 035fee98 dhcpcore!TryReceive+0x63
035feea8 706cc72a     026b7b98 035fef78 035ff2d4 dhcpcore!ProcessRecvFromSocket+0xa8
035feef8 706cb4c6     cfd3d0fc 00007ce8 035fef78 dhcpcore!GetSpecifiedDhcpMessageEx+0x40
035fef50 706ef052     cfd3d0fc 00007ce8 035fef78 dhcpcore!GetSpecifiedDhcpMessage+0x51
035ff2a0 706f1371     00000006 00000000 00000000 dhcpcore!DhcpInitState+0x35f
035ff4c0 706f1c0d     035ff4ec 035ff4e4 706f1810 dhcpcore!ObtainInitialParameters+0x1ee
035ff708 706e433e     026b7b98 00000000 706d7be0 dhcpcore!ReObtainInitialParameters+0x3fd
035ff818 77dbe2f9     026b7b98 77dbe2e0 035ff884 dhcpcore!DhcpRenewThread+0xc75e
035ff828 77ea27c7     026b7b98 e1039e85 00000000 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
035ff884 77ea279b     ffffffff 77ee2d8d 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2b
035ff894 00000000     706d7be0 026b7b98 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


SYMBOL_NAME:  afd!AfdEventSelect+13a

MODULE_NAME: afd

IMAGE_NAME:  afd.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  13a

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_CODE_AV_afd!AfdEventSelect

OS_VERSION:  10.0.17763.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {72329ad8-c7ee-3513-6ecb-5e0916af74c8}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: `afd.sys` looks to be the culprit which is as you say a network driver. Have you tried a manufactures update of the network device drivers?

Comment: I forgot to add that we have several machines with the exact same hardware and exact same driver version, so one would hope that they'd all also work the same way. Hmm.

Comment: Are the other computers exactly identical, including the upgrade, and is only this showing the problem? You could try to fix any upgrade errors with a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)